# "az network dns zone export" only exports the first 100 recordsets

Tags: azure-cli, azure-rest-api, azure-dns

Setting this question up to self-answer because I lost too much time solving it, and I want to make sure the answer is put out there for future sufferers to find and avoid the same rabbit-hole I went down...

---

### Issue

I'm trying to use the [`az network dns zone export`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/dns/zone?view=azure-cli-latest) command from the Az Cli in a PowerShell script to export the configuration from an Azure DNS Zone, but for some reason it's only exporting the  **first 100 records** if I use `az login` to connect as a Service Principal with a custom IAM role assigned.

E.g.:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest";

# see https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/26052
az config unset core.allow_broker

# log out any existing user
az logout

# log back in as the spn
az login --service-principal `
    --username "my-client-id" `
    --password "my-client-secret" `
    --tenant   "my-tenant-id"

# export the dns zone (only the first 100 records get exported :-(
az network dns zone export --resource-group "my-dns-rg" --name "mydnszone.com"
```

If I run the `az network dns zone export` command with my personal account logged in (which is an **Owner** on **My Subscription**) it works fine and exports **all 575 records**, so the problem appears to be permission-related, but it's confusing because the first 100 records *are* exported as the Service Principal so it has at least *some* permissions to read them.

### Environment

My environment setup is as follows:

- I have an Azure subscription **My Subscription**
- In this subscription I have a public Azure DNS Zone **mydnszone.com** which has **575 zone records**
- I have a custom IAM role called **My DNS Reader Role** which has the following [Microsoft.Network provider operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftnetwork) allowed:

  | Operation | Description |
  | --- | --- |
  | Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/read | Get the DNS zone, in JSON format. The zone properties include tags, etag, numberOfRecordSets, and maxNumberOfRecordSets. Note that this command does not retrieve the record sets contained within the zone. |
  | Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/recordsets/read | Gets DNS record sets across types |
- I also have an Azure Service Principal **my_dns_reader** which has been assigned **My DNS Reader Role** IAM role scoped to **My Subscription**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tl;dr

Permissions required to export *all* pages of records via the `az network dns zone export` command are:

| Operation | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Microsoft.Network/dnszones/read | Get the DNS zone, in JSON format. The zone properties include tags, etag, numberOfRecordSets, and maxNumberOfRecordSets. Note that this command does not retrieve the record sets contained within the zone. |
| Microsoft.Network/dnszones/recordsets/read | Gets DNS record sets across types |
| Microsoft.Network/dnszones/all/read | Gets DNS record sets across types |

### Summary

- The Az Cli uses the [Record Sets - List By Dns Zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/dns/record-sets/list-by-dns-zone?tabs=HTTP) Azure REST endpoint to export a dns zone with the `az network dns zone export` command.
- This endpoint uses pagination (with a default page size of 100 recordsets) to return recordsets in a DNS zone. The `Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/recordsets/read` provider operation grants access to this endpoint.
- The first page of results includes a `nextLink` which points to a *different* endpoint - [Record Sets - List **All** By Dns Zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/dns/record-sets/list-all-by-dns-zone?tabs=HTTP) - for page 2 onwards, and this endpoint requires the `Microsoft.Network/dnszones/all/read` provider operation.
- If this provider operation is missing from the current account the "Record Sets - List **All** By Dns Zone" endpoint returns paginated results but with zero rows of data in it.
- Adding the `Microsoft.Network/dnszones/all/read` to my custom IAM role allowed the `az network dns zone export` command to export **all** recordsets in the zone.

Confusingly, no error messages are shown if the `Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/recordsets/read` provider operation is present but the `Microsoft.Network/dnszones/all/read` provider operation is missing - instead the "Record Sets - List All By Dns Zone" endpoint returns pagination responses but with zero records included in the data.

### More details

Running the `az network dns zone export` command with the `--debug` flag shows it first makes a call to the [Record Sets - List By Dns Zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/dns/record-sets/list-by-dns-zone?tabs=HTTP) Azure REST endpoint - e.g.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/my-dns-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/mydnszone.com/recordsets?api-version=2023-07-01-preview
```

If the current account has the `Microsoft.Network/dnszones/recordsets/read` provider operation this returns a response in the format:

```
{
    "nextLink": "https://management.azure.com:443/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/my-dns-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnszones/mydnszone.com/ALL?api-version=2023-07-01-preview&$skipToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "value": [
      ... first 100 recordets from the dns zone ...
    ]
  }
```

(If there are less than 100 records the `nextLink` field is missing from the response).

Note that the `nextLink` ends in **`/ALL`** which is the [Record Sets - List **All** By Dns Zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/dns/record-sets/list-all-by-dns-zone?tabs=HTTP) endpoint, so subsequent calls made by the Az Cli to read paginated data hit *this* endpoint instead of the original "Record Sets - List By Dns Zone".

Unfortunately, this endpoint requires a different provider operation - namely `Microsoft.Network/dnszones/all/read` - if this is missing the response is in the following format:

```
 {
    "nextLink": "https://management.azure.com:443/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/my-dns-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnszones/mydnszone.com/ALL?api-version=2023-07-01-preview&$skipToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "value": []
  }
```

Note that pagination still works. For a zone with 575 records the `nextLink` redirects to a chain of 5 additional pages after the initial request, which is the correct number for a zone with 575 records, but the requests ending in `/ALL` contain `"value": []`.

### Epilogue

When trying to create a minimal custom IAM role for exporting dns zones, be sure to add *all* the provider operations in the "tl;dr" section at the top of this answer.